# Semaphore waiting case

Tags: c, pthreads, semaphore

I want to make sure my sempahore do what I expect to do, but I can't  bring it to the state where one or more threads wait. I need that only 3 threads at a time to be able to work over the linked list.

code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <semaphore.h>

struct dataBlock{
    struct node *root;
    int listSize;
    int forIndex;
};

struct node { // std linked list node
    int value;
    int worker;
    struct node *next;
};

int limit = 5;

sem_t sem;

pthread_mutex_t mutp = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;   // mutex
pthread_cond_t  condvar = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;   //condvar

void *deleteDoneNodes(struct node *n){
    struct node *root = n;
    struct node *it = root;
    struct node *prev = NULL;
    do{
        if(it->value == 1){
            struct node *next = it->next;
            if (prev != NULL) {
                prev->next = next;
            }
            if (it == root) {
                root = next;
            }
            free(it);
            it = next;
        }
        else {
            prev = it;
            it = it->next;
        }
    }while(it !=  NULL);

    return root;
}

void * worker( void *data ){
    //get list
    int wFlag;
    struct dataBlock *inData = ( struct dataBlock * ) data;
    struct node *root = inData->root;
    int forIndex = inData ->forIndex;
    free(data);


    while(1){

        if( sem_wait( &sem )  != 0 ){
            printf( " > waiting...  \n" );
        }
        // pthread_mutex_lock( &mutp );
        struct node *it = root;

        do{
            if( forIndex == it->worker ){
                if( it->value > 2 ){
                    while( it->value != 1 )
                    it->value = sqrt(it->value);
                }
            }
            else{
                // printf("Not sqrt-able node %d\n",it->value);
            }
            it = it->next;
        }while(it !=  NULL);

        // pthread_cond_signal( &condvar ); 
        // pthread_mutex_unlock( &mutp );
        sem_post(&sem); 
        // sleep(100); // "create" concurrancy envi.
        pthread_exit(0);    
    }

    return NULL;
}



int main( int argc, char *argv[] ){
    if ( argc != 3 ){
        printf( "Programm must be called with \n NR of elements and NR of workers! \n " );
        exit( 1 );
    }

    int i;
    struct node *root;
    struct node *iterator;  

//prepare list for task
    int listSize = atoi(argv[1]);
    int nrWorkers = atoi(argv[2]);
    root = malloc(sizeof( struct node) );

    root->value = rand() % 100;
    root->worker = 0;
    iterator = root;

    for( i=1; i<listSize; i++ ){
        iterator->next = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        iterator = iterator->next;
        iterator->value = rand() % 100;
        iterator->worker = i % nrWorkers;
        printf("node #%d worker: %d  value: %d\n", i, iterator->worker,iterator->value);
    }
    iterator->next = NULL;
    printf("? List got populated\n");
// init semaphore > keeps max 3 threads working over the list

    if( sem_init(&sem,0,3) < 0){
      perror("semaphore initilization");
      exit(0);
    }

// Create all threads to parse the link list
    int ret;    
    pthread_mutex_init(&mutp,NULL);

    pthread_t w_thread;
    pthread_t* w_threads = malloc(nrWorkers * sizeof(w_thread));

    for( i=0; i < nrWorkers; i++ ){         
        struct dataBlock *data = malloc(sizeof(struct dataBlock));
        data->root = root;
        data->listSize = listSize;
        data->forIndex = i;
        ret = pthread_create ( &w_threads[i], NULL, worker, (void *) data );
        if( ret ) {
            perror("Thread creation fail");
            exit(2);    
        }   
    } 

    deleteDoneNodes( root );

    int join;
    for ( i = 0; i < nrWorkers; i++ ){
        join = pthread_join(w_threads[i],NULL);
    }

    iterator = root;
    for ( i = 0; i < listSize; i++){
        printf("val: %d  worker: %d _  \n", iterator->value, iterator->worker);
        iterator = iterator->next;
    }

    free(root);
    free(iterator);
    sem_destroy(&sem);
    return 0;
}
```

terminal~> ./s 16 16

```
node #1 worker: 1  value: 86
node #2 worker: 2  value: 77
node #3 worker: 3  value: 15
node #4 worker: 4  value: 93
node #5 worker: 5  value: 35
node #6 worker: 6  value: 86
node #7 worker: 7  value: 92
node #8 worker: 8  value: 49
node #9 worker: 9  value: 21
node #10 worker: 10  value: 62
node #11 worker: 11  value: 27
node #12 worker: 12  value: 90
node #13 worker: 13  value: 59
node #14 worker: 14  value: 63
node #15 worker: 15  value: 26
? List got populated
val: 1  worker: 0 _  
val: 1  worker: 1 _  
val: 1  worker: 2 _  
val: 1  worker: 3 _  
val: 1  worker: 4 _  
val: 1  worker: 5 _  
val: 1  worker: 6 _  
val: 1  worker: 7 _  
val: 1  worker: 8 _  
val: 1  worker: 9 _  
val: 1  worker: 10 _  
val: 1  worker: 11 _  
val: 1  worker: 12 _  
val: 1  worker: 13 _  
val: 1  worker: 14 _  
val: 1  worker: 15 _
```

Comment: What is that you expect to happen but does not? Did you try putting the commented `sleep()` *inside* the `sem_wait()`/`sem_post()` block, instead of outside?

Comment: Don't reinitialize your mutex dynamically. The static initialization is completely sufficient. What is the use of `w_thread`? Is it just to compute the `sizeof` of the `pthread_t` type? All that shows that you first should go through your code yourself, work out a concrete question, boil it down to something reproducible, and then come back. SO is not for code review.

Comment: @flavo why would i do that?! i need the thread to wait, before doing anything

Comment: You said "I can't bring it to the state where one or more threads wait", so I suggested to move the `sleep` in order to force some threads to wait for the semaphore. However, as @Jens and I already said, try to clarify what you are asking.

Comment: @Flavio  "I need that only 3 threads at a time to be able to work over the linked list." meaning from more than 3 threads, 3 should eba ble to access the list...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see some potential bugs in your code.

First, I think your critic zone are all the nodes, so you should protect all accesses with a mutex. In your worker you're not doing that.

Your semaphore, though, should work: Initialized with 3 and with sem_wait in the beginning of the thread function and sem_post in the end.

So, the biggest possible problem I can think of is your deletenodes function.
Don't forget that main will also be a thread, and since you're deleting the nodes before the join and your data sent to the threads are constructed with pointers, if all of your threads loses the processor before handling the data, and your main thread gets the processor, it will clean all the nodes making your data type, passed to the worker threads, obsolete, empty, null in the best case. 
This happens, like I said, because you pass the value to data by pointers/reference and not by copy. I can see two possible solutions: Either you call delete nodes after the join(wich will set your main thread state to blocked, asserting that your call to delete nodes happens after all threads ended) or you pass the values to data by copy(wich will, in my opinion, give you much more work).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use a thread pool from glib "http://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Thread-Pools.html"

Comment: I think that the user is looking for a level of understanding to get the posted code to work, not a library that solves the problem entirely.